# Django - URL routing issues (cannot import name 'urls')

Tags: python, django, url, routes, django-urls

I am following the Django tutorial on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/, and am trying to get the index view to show up. I've tried the code specified on the page verbatim but keep on getting errors.

polls/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, urls
    from polls import views

    urlpatterns = patterns('', 
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
)
```

mysite/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

)

and finally, the index method in views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

def index(request): 
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting an error that says "cannot import name 'urls'." any help would be appreciated!

Comment: give stack trace of error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is in your `import` statement - there is no `urls` function in `django.conf.urls` package.

Replace:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, urls
```

with:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
```